# Easiest way to create a sign-over url with OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, single-sign-on

I would appreciate any links or examples as I am new to this and do not know where to start from. My application has basic authentication, I need to add OAuth to enable SSO, automatic log in a third party application.

1. Modify my user model to store OAuth parameters, modify a controller with login/logout actions
2. Use OmniAuth
   https://github.com/intridea/omniauth
3. Devise and OmniAuth: 
   Create the standard devise User model and migration.
   Create the Auth Controller actions (as show in the code snippet below)
   Create the AccessGrant model (and if required the Authentication model)
   Register the client applications (key and secret) via rails console on User Manager.
4. Use the oauth gem
   https://github.com/albertopq/oauth-activeresource

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2nd variant. It will be easier than others and you won't have any problems with integration another gems.